# Ruby: Reading a json file get `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, json, flurry

I'm working on a Ruby code that receive a json file (from Flurry API) and create another json friendly-format for "Status Board" app. When using this json fragment:

```
"country":[{"@country":"US","day":[{"@date":"2013-09-20","@value":"1"},
{"@date":"2013-09-   23","@value":"1"}]},
{"@country":"KR","day":{"@date":"2013-09-20","@value":"1"}}
```

Everything works fine, but when the code read "KR" and then "day" (note the lack of "[]") I receive the following error:

- `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

The code I use to read the original json file is:

```
countries = response.parsed_response["country"]
   countries.each do |datapoint|
      countryName = datapoint["@country"]
      days = datapoint["day"]
      data = []
      days.each do |datapoint2|
          value = datapoint2["@value"]
          date = Date.parse(datapoint2["@date"])
          dateString = date.strftime(dateFormat)
          data << { :title => dateString, :value => value }
      end
      dataSequences << { :title => countryName, :color => metric[:color], :datapoints => data 
   }
   end
```

I'm kind of noob in Ruby, so...It is possible to add brackets when reading a json file to avoid this error?

Comment: Which line is pointed by your error?
EDIT: You probably pass `String` instance to `Array#[]` method somewhere.

Comment: The error shows right after: "days.each do |datapoint2|". It fails reading "@value" or "@date" (I'm tried both). When I print datapoint2 it shows: {"@date":"2013-09-20","@value":"1"} -> Without brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby includes a few type coercion methods that you might find useful.

The first is `Array()`, which will convert its argument into an array, unless the argument is already one, it which case it simply returns the argument:

```
Array(1) #=> [1]
Array([1,2,3]) #=> [1,2,3]
```

Somewhat annoyingly, when fed a single hash, it converts the hash into an array of arrays (the key-value pairs in the hash):

```
Array({ a: 1, b: 2}) #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
```

However, there is also a `Hash[]` method that will convert that result back into a hash, but leave existing hashes alone:

```
Hash[ [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]] ] #=> { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Since your 'day' key is sometimes an array of hashes and sometimes a single hash, you can use these in your method to ensure your iterations and lookups work as expected:

```
Array(datapoint["day"]).each do |datapoint2|
  dp2_hash = Hash[datapoint2]
  # ... etc, substituting future mentions of datapoint2 with dp2_hash
```